# What sources of magic would oppose each other?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, magic

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I honestly did not know how to search for it properly as my question is more broadly than the arcana class Wizards use, which is often what I find. Rather, I am more confused about the broader scope; understanding how one class of magic might perceive the others, which one they would feel as a competitive rival, and which ones would be complete oppositions.

> For instance, I read that druid magic is sourced by nature and has a
> strong focus on maintaining the natural life cycle. Therefore, it is
> directly opposed to undead creatures and necromancy, which defies such
> an order. However, I am still unsure how the druids feel about other
> forms of arcana, eldritch, or divine magic. Would they see an Archfey Warlock as
> a cousin to their cause?

Given that they can be sourced from warring factions such as devils, demons, and celestials, I thought that there would be more lore readily available, but perhaps due to my lack of effectively communicating my query in a single question, I am not finding the answer.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing a step, but is there a particular reason your second paragraph is quote formatted? It doesn't seem to be a quote from anywhere.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without specifying a campaign setting.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Trying to give an example while keeping the question broad. IE, I wanted it view as an example and not the main focus.

Comment: @indigochild does it really change that much? Been studying the PHB and trying to understand the lore around the classes...

Comment: Are you just asking if Enchantment Wizards have beef with Evocation Wizards? (Or if any schools have beef with any other schools)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov not really focusing on the schools of magic, but more the sources and the discourse classes/subclasses might have. For instance are clerics friendly towards draconic sorcerers (given celestials and dragons hate each other)? Do druids find an ally with archfey warlocks but despise undying warlocks? ... Or are they all friendly despite being political opposites, so to speak. Most of what I read keeps Nature magic, Arcana Magic, and Divine Magic as 3 separate things that don't interact, so I am wondering how they do.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov For the schools, I know that all magic users have access to some necrotic spells or divine spells... so I don't think that the school itself would be the focus. Rather the fact that druids (for example) are against the undead, so they might not be too friendly towards a necromancer seeking lichdom. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn’t really anything like this.

Certain forces, groups, or ideologies may oppose certain **uses** for magic. For instance, druids may be opposed to using necromancy to thwart death, because it is “unnatural.” Many clerics—as in, almost-all of the good ones and a large chunk of the neutral ones—oppose it also, because it is “evil.” But this is specific opposition to undeath in all its forms—not in what sort of magic created them. And it’s consistent with the broader themes of each of these groups—druids oppose all things unnatural, good clerics oppose all things evil.

Moreover, you conflate undeath and necromancy, but that’s not accurate. Necromancy can do a lot of things unrelated to undead creatures—and druids have no problem with those uses of necromancy. Indeed, several necromancy spells, such as *blight*, are “classic” druid spells. *Blight* has nothing to do with the undead, and druids don’t have a problem with it.

Anyway, there is no objection to arcane magic among divine-magic users, no objection to divine magic among nature-magic users, and so on. Eldritch magic has some opposition—from everybody, simply because it is dangerous. But again, this is more like the opposition to undead creatures—it’s not like a fiend-patron warlock is any **more** objectionable than a fiend-summoning wizard.

There are a few specific exceptions. I don’t believe 5e has printed any of them, but there are a number of god-hating groups within the wider canon of D&D, such as ethergaunts and ur-priests. They object to divine magic. And in the *Dark Sun* campaign setting, arcane magic is universally feared and hated—because in that setting, arcane magic needs to draw upon the life force of the surrounding environment, and its overuse has turned the entire planet to a barren husk. But these are special exceptions, and you find rather the opposite thing in other exceptional situations: for example, in the Forgotten Realms, **all magic** ultimately comes from Mystra, even the non-divine ones. An objection to a particular type of magic wouldn’t make any sense there.

Comment: Thank you. It was more of the "druids oppose all things unnatural, good clerics oppose all things evil." part that I was trying to get at more than the school of magic. Though, I did think that the source of the spellcaster's power did hold more meaning. But I am confused on that second to last question: I thought Mystra gave arcana while divine and nature were two other sources...

Comment: @VictorB These kinds of ideological positions are usually at the class level. Power source has a lot of meaning with respect to how the power is gained or exercised; you pray for divine spells vs. study for wizard spells, etc. It’s just that these differences don’t tend to be things that others object to. (Also, to an extent, it’s that 5e has largely elided these distinctions—we don’t even really have, say, bard, sorcerer, and wizard grouped as “arcane” anymore. Past editions did somewhat more with it, though still rarely in a way that made users of one predisposed towards users of another.)

Comment: @VictorB As for Mystra, she controls the Weave and without the Weave, there is no magic. Shar has a replacement in the Shadow Weave, but other than that, deities rely on the Weave as much as mortals do, I believe. So even if they are sending to their own power to their clerics, they are using the Weave to do it.